# [Wine/PoL]Skyrim cannot properly detect my graphics card

Tags: wine, games, playonlinux

I have an AMD R9-285 and installed the 14.5 driver from AMD.

```
display: :0  screen: 0
OpenGL vendor string: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc.
OpenGL renderer string: AMD Radeon R9 200 Series
OpenGL version string: 4.4.13283 Compatibility Profile Context 14.501.1003
```

But Skyrim can only detect it as an ATI Radeon HD 5600 Series.

After changing one of the values in Regedit, disabled the GLSL under Wine, Skyrim detected it as another lower GPU and the game cannot run. Maybe the performance will greatly improve once my GPU got detected properly.